# Cross Domain Issue : Camel Swagger with Jetty in a Karaf Environment

Tags: java, apache-camel, jetty, swagger-ui, apache-karaf

I'm working in a OSGi environment project. I have discovered that camel offer an integration for swagger. So i have used it. It's working well until launching a request with swagger UI.

I mean when i put in swagger ui the uri i have defined with camel-swagger-java, it works. Swagger discovers my api !

But when i want to launch a request with swagger ui, i have some issue with cross domain request.

I have found several solutions :
 - first one with camel rest

```
restConfiguration().component("jetty").bindingMode(RestBindingMode.json)
        .dataFormatProperty("prettyPrint", "true")
        .contextPath("/").port(8080).apiContextPath("/api-doc/login").apiProperty("api.title", "Login API").apiProperty("api.version", "1.0.0-SNAPSHOT")
        .apiProperty("cors", "true").apiProperty("apiContextIdListing", "true");
```

I have set to true cors property. But it didn't solved my issue. Then after some search, i found it might be jetty which forbidden cross domain request. But a this point, i have not found how to configure Jetty in a OSGi environment (Karaf / Fellix) to accept this kind of request.

Thanks for your help

Comment: You need to turn on CORS

Comment: On jetty ? How ? I think with .apiProperty("cors", "true") it's good for camel. But with Jetty  in a OSGi context, i didn't found how to do it. That's my problem :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a solution. With Camel i had to create OPTIONS Rest Interface per Service. It's very dirty(http://camel.465427.n5.nabble.com/Workaround-with-REST-DSL-to-avoid-HTTP-method-not-allowed-405-td5771508.html). So I used this solution : github.com/swagger-api/swagger-ui/issues/1888